# JUNG graph with two different verices

Tags: java, graphics, graph, jung

The graph interface clearly gives two paramters:

```
Graph<Vertex, Edges>
```

I would like to draw a graph with two different kind of vertices. I have not found anything to realize this with the JUNG API is it possible or do I have to write a work around?

---

In my case I want to realize a [resource-allocation graph](http://www.sci.csueastbay.edu/~billard/cs4560/node10.html):

I already have two classes: MonitorInfo and ThreadInfo. I would like to use both as vertices in my graph.

Comment: Why are you trying to mix `String` vertices and `Integer` vertices in the same graph? Once we know that, we may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: @Adam Paynter: Oh String and Integer is not my actual case, I added it to my question what I actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make `MonitorInfo` and `ThreadInfo` implement a common interface. For example, they could both implement `Info`. Now, you can declare the graph as type `Graph<Info, Edges>`. Of course, JUNG doesn't come with the functionality to isolate *just* the `MonitorInfo` vertices or *just* the `ThreadInfo` vertices, but at least it will work with *some* type safety (as opposed to using a `Graph<Object, Edge>`.

Comment: What does a computer scientist if we cannot solve a problem? Add another abstraction layer. Thanks!

Comment: @platzhirsch: I often use that motto! :) "Nothing another layer of abstraction won't fix!"